# Undefined reference to randomInteger

Tags: c++

I am having a problem when I am trying to include an use a function from a header that I created. 
Below is my header file: random.h

```
#ifndef _random_h
#define _random_h

int randomInteger(int low, int high);

#endif // _random_h
```

Next is my implementation file: random.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "random.h"
using namespace std;

int randomInteger(int low, int high)
{
    return 1200;
}
```

Now this is my main program below: helloworld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "random.h"


int main()
{
    int num = randomInteger(10, 110);
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I am getting an error when I run my main program which says 
**undefined reference to randomInteger(int, int).**

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: You either didn't compile `random.cpp` or the obj file generated by it isn't linked properly.

Comment: I am using codeblocks for window

Comment: LOL reminds me of this [joke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/237826/1870232)

Comment: i compiled the random.cpp and i get an error that says undefined reference to 'winMain16'

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile random.cpp and helloworld.cpp with the `-c` flag (assuming gcc/g++), for compile only. As this will just create you an object file, and won't look for a specific main function()

Then you need to compile with something like this `g++ -o myprogramtorun random.o helloworld.o`

OR you can do it in one step like this:

`g++ -o myprogramtorun random.cpp helloworld.cpp` but this becomes unsustainable